# Sparse matrix in matlab: set unrecorded elements to -1 instead of 0

Tags: matlab, coding-efficiency

I want to create a sparse matrix consisting mainly of -1, but also includes some 0 and 1.  This is part of a larger project, so it is important that I do not switch -1 with 0.  As default, sparse(A) in Matlab keeps track of only non-zero elements.  Is there a way to keep track of only non-(minus one) elements?  For example, if

```
A = 
-1 -1 -1  0 
 1 -1 -1 -1
```

Then

```
new_sparse(A) =
(1,4) = 0
(2,1) = 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you define `A = sparse([1 2], [4 1], [1 2])` and modify your code to instead of `A` use `A-1`? (but not explicitly, or you may lose the sparsity)

Comment: Luis: Yup that works, thanks.  I was hoping that Matlab had a cleaner solution, so that I do not have to alter the (already written) code downstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to override `sparse` to use different values. What you can do, though time and memory consuming, is to use `accumarray`:

```
x_ind; % I presume this to contain the column index of the number
y_ind; % I presume this to contain the row  index of the number
value; % I presume this to contain the value (0 or 1)
new_mat = accumarray([x_ind y_ind],value,[],[],-1);
```

`new_mat` now will contain your prescribed `0` and `1` values, and has `-1` on all other locations. You do not have to set the `size` argument (the third) since it will just create a matrix of `max(x_ind) x max(y_ind)` size if you put `[]`. The fourth input argument, the function, can be empty as well, since each combination of `x_ind` and `y_ind` will contain only one value, thus the default, `mean` is sufficient.

An example:

```
A = [0 1 ; -1 0];
x_ind = [1;2;2];
y_ind = [1;1;2];
value = [0;1;0];
new_mat = accumarray([x_ind y_ind],value,[],[],-1);

new_mat = 
          0    1
          -1   0
```

A different method which I'd prefer is to simply add one to all values, thus making your 1 2 and setting your 0 to 1. This way -1 is mapped to 0 and therefore you're clear to use `sparse` anyway. In the example this would set `A = [1 2;0 1]` which you can call with your respective values using `A-1`.

Just as a note: `sparse` stores three values for each element (row, column, value), plus some overhead. So if your matrix is less than about 70% empty, `sparse` is actually consuming *more* memory than a regular, full matrix.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  Can you please provide an example?  I get an error, but that's probably because I miss-interpreted your answer.

If 
A = [0 1 ; -1 0] 
say, then is it true that: 
x_ind = [1 ; 2 ; 2] (0 appears col 1, 1 appears col 2, 0 appears col 2);
y_ind = [1 ; 1 ; 2] (0 appears row 1, 1 appears row 1, 0 appears row 2);
value = [0 ; 1 ; 0] (values are 0, 1, 0);
new_mat = accumarray(x_ind,y_ind,value,[],[],-1)?

Doing this, I get the following error:
Third input SZ must be a full
row vector with one element for
each column of SUBS.

Comment: Weird you get that error. Setting the third argument to `[]` should make it use the default; see my updated answer.

Comment: I still get an error after directly copying your code into R2015b: Error using accumarray When SUBS is a column vector, the third input SZ must be of the form [N 1].  This is strange because SZ or value is 3x1.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I remember again, I always do this wrong, apologies. I updated the answer. The `[x_ind y_ind]` should be 1 argument, not two  as I put it.

Comment: I did not know about the 70% empty condition, thanks!

Comment: You can of course make a matrix with only 10% zero-elements sparse, but that'll just increase memory. So it is not a *strict* condition in the sense that it won't work otherwise, but more as a rule of thumb. `whos A` gives you its size in bytes (in your RAM), check it yourself for sparse and non-sparse matrices containing the same values.