# Efficient creation of logical sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

My goal is to create a rectangular grid and assign a yes/no value to each point. I wans a quite large grid, so I decided to store it as a sparse matrix. My approach considers an `N x N` grid, with only a ratio `r` of points to be true (so `Nact = r*N^2` points):

```
N = 200;
r = 0.25;
NAct = r*N^2;
ss = spalloc(ceil(N),ceil(N),ceil(NAct));
for j = 1:N, for i = 1:N, ss(i,j) = rand < r; end; end;
ssL = logical(ss);
```

However this seems not efficient for large `N`.

I also tried this:

```
N = 200;
r = 0.25;
NAct = r*N^2;
iAct = randi(N,1,N);
jAct = randi(N,1,N);
sssL = sparse(iAct,jAct,true,ceil(N),ceil(N),ceil(NAct));
nnz(sssL)
```

as an alternative, but I have two problems: the `true` points are `N` instead of `NAct`, and there is an error if two pairs of elements of `iAct` and `jAct` coincide.

Comment: Sparse matrix have no advantages in terms of space if compared to logicals in most cases. With threshold `0.25` logical `200x200` array takes 40000 bytes compared to 92139 bytes taken by sparse. Only matrices with very few nonzero entries take less space than logicals.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32444192/5211833) of mine about the memory efficiency of sparse-matrices, especially the last paragraph. Gist is that `sparse` is only useful if you have 70% or more zero-entries in your system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find K random different pixels in an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403738/how-to-find-k-random-different-pixels-in-an-image)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34404331/1377097) will give you the code you need to get exactly `NAct` distinct random elements.

Comment: @brainkz and @Adriaan, I am aware of that, however `nnz < (N(N-1)-1)/2` for this application or the zero entries are 75%. I cannot create a full `NxN` matrix due to memory shortage, but I manage to allocate what I need with `spalloc`; it's the double loop that is inefficient.

Comment: @beaker, I cannot see how I can use this.

Comment: @Theo Given the `[X,Y]` return results from user664303's answer, `sssL = sparse(X,Y,true,...)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally used `sprand`

```
N = 200;
r = 0.25;
NAct = r*N^2;
ss = sprand(N,N,r);
ssL = logical(ss);
```

Comment: Very nice! This seems like the most direct method.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = 200;
Grid(N,N) = false; %// preallocate grid
Grid = sparse(Grid); %// add to make sparse
r = 213;
TruePoints = randi(N^2,r,1); %// get random indices of points to be true
Grid(TruePoints) = true;
Grid = logical(Grid); %// switch to logical
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this produces a full matrix. I already use something like `Grid = rand(N) < R` for a full matrix, but I need a sparse one.

Comment: @Theo you can fix that easily, see the update. Apparently `sparse logical` matrices exist.

Comment: Only double and logical sparse matrices exist in matlab.

Comment: fantastic. That makes this answer what you want isn't it?

Comment: Yes, although I found another solution, which seems slightly quicker. Anyway, I wanted to avoid an temporary full matrix converted to sparse. I have also edited your answer, because `r` is the ratio of true points, and not their number.

Comment: @Theo I wasn't around to approve or reject your edit, but be aware that usually edits to code of other will be rejected. 2 robo-reviewers apparently approved it due to your edit summary, but it's best to suggest the edit to the author of the code in a comment (if possible). Good job on your solution.

Comment: I am sorry, I wasn't aware of that. I thought it would be better to avoid bothering you more, but I will follow your advice from now on. Thank you!